# Nativescript-vue graphql backend?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Just started to experiment with `nativescript-vue`. Since it's pretty new, can't seem find good documentation on nativescript-vue integration with graphql. Tried [`vue-apollo`](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo), but can't install. When I do `vue add apollo`, it errors out. Is there any good docs on how to integrate nativescript-vue with graphql backend or more specifically via `apollo`?

Comment: I tried using Apollo with NS-Vue, there was some issue. But, It's working with axios.

Answer (score 2):

I want to confirm that **nativescript-vue is working properly with vue-apollo**.

You should first install apollo-boost using npm or yarn

```sh
yarn add vue-apollo graphql apollo-boost
```

main.ts

```js
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
import routes from "./routes";
import store from "./store";
import * as ApplicationSettings from "tns-core-modules/application-settings";

import VueApollo from "vue-apollo";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";

// GET TOKEN and Prepare for header bearer
const tokenInAppSet = ApplicationSettings.getString("token")
    ? ApplicationSettings.getString("token").replace(/['"]+/g, "")
    : false;

/////////////// APOLLO 
export const defaultClient = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://000.com/graphql",
    headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${tokenInAppSet}`,
    }
});

Vue.use(VueApollo);
const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
    defaultClient,
});

new Vue({
    store,
    apolloProvider,
    render: (h) =>
        h("frame", [h(tokenInAppSet ? routes.entered : routes.login)]),
}).$start();
```

If you want to see some installed version.

Vue-Apollo with Nativescript examples:

https://github.com/kaanguru/apollo-jwt

https://github.com/kaanguru/simple-question

Comment: Thanks, now I still need to get websockets for subscriptions to work. Any idea/repos?

Comment: I can suggest using `tns debug android --no-hmr` .  Most errors were not nativescript-vue related  
https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/apollo/subscriptions.html#setup

Comment: That didn't do it, I asked a separate question with the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62357603/error-cannot-read-property-slice-of-undefined-when-importing-apollo-link-ws